# Galios Field Theory

Tags: galois-theory, maple

$GF(29)^2$ is created by adjoining the root of the irreducible quadratic $p=x^2+7x+15$ to the field $GF(29)$ . The cubic polynomial $q=Y^3+(26x+26)Y^2+(8x+22)Y+13x+23$ is irreducible over this new field.

a. If the root of the given cubic is adjoined to $GF(29)^2$ in order to form a larger field extension, how many elements are in the new field?

b. Using the matrix representation find the product of the two polynomials $Y^2+x+1$ and $Y^2+xY+1$
I know how to make fields and how to generate companion matrix and do the multiplication of the given polynomials in part b.

But I am not sure that I am building the matrix correctly. I need help in understanding the question properly.

It is my assignment question I am not looking for a straight answer but for well build explanation which helps me understand the base concept.

Comment: In (b): **whose** matrix representation??

Comment: In (a): you add a root $\;w\;$ of an irreducible cubic to field $\;K\;$ , so you get that $\;\dim_K K(w)=3\;$ , so if $\;|K|=r\;$ , then $\;|K(w)|=r^3\;$ ...

Comment: For part a... what I understood from lecture...is that prof. say that if we have a Gf(2) we have ground elements as 0 and 1 later he adjoins  x and say not the field has 4 elements... 0,1,x and x +1.... So here it says 29... so ground field will be 0-28 but dnt knw what to do for the cubic...step

Comment: This time, if I didn't misunderstood, your ground field has $\;29^2\;$ elements, so...it's the same as in the basic case over the prime field!

Comment: Ya but then we are adjoining a cubic which means it can be 29^2^3 ... I dont know if I am geting this correct

Comment: Well @Denial...so? It in fact is $\;\left(29^2\right)^3=29^6\;$

Comment: So what will be my no. of elements... Do i have to add roots of the polynomial... along with 29^6... Like prof. did in his example of x and x +1

Comment: What isn't clear, @denial? The field will have $\;29^6\;$ elements, as already said: these will be the cosets of all the polynomials of the form $\;ax^2+bx+c\;,\;\;a,b,c\in GF(29^2)\;$ in the quotient $\;GF(29^2)[x]/(q)\;$ ...